# Is there a way to add custom tracks to DJ Hero?

Tags: mods, dj-hero

I remember with the older Guitar Hero games it was possible to hotswap and add custom tracks to the game, is there anything like this possible on DJ Hero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not right now- there's been [progress on customs](http://www.scorehero.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=1543204), but the game won't load custom tracks at the moment.